# After insert, after delete, after, update Trigger not Working

Tags: apex, trigger

What I need to do is basically create a trigger in `Opportunitylineitem` where in if I try to add,edit,delete an `OpportunitylineItem` it will calculate a created custom created fields in the `Opportunity` object. `Opportunity` object is a look-up of `Opportunitylineitem`.

I have this code but I don't know why it is not working, It does not throw an error either. Can someone help me with this one.

OpportunityLineItem Trigger

```
trigger TotalOpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();

if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
}
else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
}
else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.old);
}


}
```

and this is my trigger Handler

```
public class TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler {



    public void TotalField(List<OpportunityLineItem> o){


         //map set and use the set in the list

         //Set<ID> idLine = new Set<ID>();                        

         //for(OpportunityLineItem oL : o){
         //idLine.add(oL.id);
         //}

         //List<OpportunityLineItem> olList = [Select id , (select id, listPrice from product2)]; 


         List<Opportunity> opporList = [select id, Total_List_Price__c, Total_End_User_Price__c,
                                    Total_End_User_Price_Discount__c, Total_Standard_Price__c,
                                    Total_Standard_Price_Discount__c, Total_SPR_Price__c, Total_SPR_Price_Discount__c,
                                    Total_Price__c, Total_Price_Discount__c, Total_SPR_Margin__c from Opportunity];


        for(Opportunity oppor : opporList){
            for(OpportunityLineItem oL : o){

              oppor.Total_List_Price__c =+ ol.ListPrice; //+= field for summation
              //insert calculation
              //another for loop for the value
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: First of all all your actions are after so you have to update explicity.And your code queries entire opportunity and for each opportunity it loops in whatever opportunity line item is edited/deleted/inserted, this is not a good practice.Please check

Comment: @PreyaMohandoss Well basically the Opportunity fields that are in the query are the fields that will  be calculated.
Now I just tried to add one field in my calculation to see if my code is working but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use a trigger instead of Rollup Summary fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments, and Lance Shi, have already pointed out the reason why you weren't seeing any results (after trigger means you need to explicitly perform the DML).

What I'm here to do is suggest an alternative to your current code.

I see a few issues with your current code:

- You're querying for *all* `Opportunities` (the query isn't selective)
- It doesn't perform a check to see if a given `OpportunityLineItem` belongs to the current `Opportunity` (you'll be adding financials to Opps other than the `Opportunity` that a given line item is on)
- You aren't checking to see if any of the `OpportunityLineItem` fields you're summing are null (Apex will complain loudly if you try to += `null`)
- You're only working with the `OpportunityLineItems` that have been triggered (it's not an idempotent operation, and is susceptible to being added twice if you have a workflow field update on `OpportunityLineItem`)
- There doesn't seem to be anything stopping the `OpportunityLineItems` from being added to the `Opportunity` again if an `OpportunityLineItem` happens to be updated more than once in its lifetime

Generally speaking, this is something that should be handled by Rollup Summary Fields on `Opportunity`.

Failing that, Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) would be another good solution.

The DLRS tool makes its own triggers, so it may not work super well with the Trigger Handler pattern (or other trigger frameworks). By that, I mean that getting it integrated with such patterns is likely a chore, and would mean you'd be losing the ability to maintain things declaratively.

If neither of those methods are viable in your situation, it comes down to writing code ourselves. What you have is a start, but I think we can do better.

Instead of manually repeating the same summing logic over and over in a for loop, you can let a SOQL query do the heavy lifting by using [SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm).

Also, instead of querying all `Opportunities`, you can improve things by using the sObject constructor, which allows you to set the Id field (and is used in a nifty pattern for updating sObjects).

It takes just a little bit of additional setup

```
Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();

// First step, loop over your Opp Line Items to figure out exactly which Opportunities
//   we are working with.
for(OpportunityLineItem oli :o){
    opportunityIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
}

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

// Now, we can move on to the query, which will do 95% of our work for us.
// I can only guess at your field names on Opp Line Item.
// The general syntax of an aggregate function is 'OPERATION(field) alias'.
// The alias isn't required, but I find it makes retrieving the results easier.
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT OpportunityId,
        SUM(ListPrice) TotalListPrice, SUM(End_User_Price__c) TotalEndUserPrice,
        SUM(End_User_Price_Discount__c) TotalEndUserPriceDiscount, SUM(Standard_Price__c) TotalStandardPrice,
        SUM(Standard_Price_Discount__c) TotalStandardPriceDiscount, SUM(SPR_Price__c) TotalSPRPrice,
        SUM(SPR_Price_Discount__c) TotalSPRPriceDiscount, SUM(TotalPrice) TotalPrice,
        SUM(Total_Price_Discount__c) TotalPriceDiscount, SUM(SPR_Margin__c) TotalSPRMargin
    FROM OpportunityLineItem 
    WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityIds 
    GROUP BY OpportunityId]){
        // Now we build the Opportunities that we'll be updating using the sObject 
        //   constructor
        oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(
            // The main downside of using Aggregate functions is that we get an
            //   AggregateResult as a result, which means we need to cast everything
            //    (and use .get('<field name or alias>') )
            Id = (Id)ar.get('OpportunityId'),

            // While SUM() won't complain about trying to add a null value like normal Apex
            //   would, if all of the values that get summed are null, the result
            //   will be null.
            // It's still a good idea to do a null check.
            // For that, I use the ternary condition operator 
            //   (boolean expresssion) ? (value or expression if true) : (value or expression if false)
            // This is also where the aliases come in handy.
            // Otherwise it'd be ar.get('expr0'), ar.get('expr1'), etc...
            Total_List_Price__c = ar.get('TotalListPrice') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalListPrice'),
            Total_End_User_Price__c = ar.get('TotalEndUserPrice') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalEndUserPrice'),

            // more of the same, omitted for brevity

            Total_SPR_Margin__c = ar.get('TotalSPRMargin') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('TotalSPRMargin')
        ));
}

update oppsToUpdate;
```

This result:

- cuts down on the amount of looping that we do
- makes the rollup an idempotent operation (meaning that if you don't change any of the numbers on the Opp Line Items, you can run this code any number of times, and the results on the Opp will turn out the same each time)
- is more robust

It's possible to take this idea further as well, using custom settings, another custom object, or custom metadata types to be able to declaratively manage which fields you want to roll up.

This would require a good amount of extra effort, and would likely end up looking a lot like the DLRS tool.

**+edit:**

The weakness of using SOQL aggregate functions here is that the query is on the `OpportunityLineItem`. This means that if an `Opportunity` has no `OpportunityLineItems` on it, the query won't find anything to work on, and the `Opportunity` will be stuck with the rolled-up data from the transaction before it lost all of its Line Items.

This is a perfect example of why you should consider rollup summary fields or the DLRS tool before trying to do it yourself with code. It's easy to miss edge cases like this.

However, with a bit more code, we can handle this situation.

First, let's declare another `Set<Id>` up by where we declared `Set<Id> opportunityIds`.

```
Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> summedOppIds = new Set<Id>();
...
```

Now, inside the for loop, you can add the Opportunity Id to this new set

```
for(AggregateResult ar :[query omitted]){
    // In this loop, we know for a fact that there is at least 1
    //   OpportunityLineItem on the current Opportunity.
    // Add the OpportunityId to our new set so we know that we've handled this
    //   particular Opportunity.
    summedOppIds.add((Id)ar.get('OpportunityId'));

    // rest of summing logic remains the same

}
```

After the summing loop has finished, we have 2 pieces of information

1. Which Opportunity Ids do we need to update?
2. Which Opportunity Ids have we summed?

With this, we can determine which `Opportunities` (if any) weren't handled by the previous logic (which should only occur when an `Opportunity` has all of its remaining Line Items deleted).

Using the `removeAll()` set method, and a simple for loop, we can handle these `Opportunities`.

```
// Removing all the summedOppIds from our target oppotunityIds leaves us with
//   the Opps that still need attention.
// There's no need for casting here.
opportunityIds.removeAll(summedOppIds);

for(Id oppId :opportunityIds){
    oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(
        Id = oppId,
        Total_List_Price__c = 0,

        // other fields omitted for brevity

        Total_SPR_Margin__c = 0
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi Derek I tried your code from above and it's working perfectly fine, just a question when I am deleting an item, it's not throwing null like for example ListPrice = 4000, I deleted one product and then it became 2000, but then when I try to delete the otherone it still stays the same. How can I fix that? and also How can I incorporate my own formula in your code thanks in advance, For example Opportunity.Total_End_Price_Discount__c = (1 – Opportunity.Total End User Price / Opportunity.Total List Price) x 100%

Comment: @JMDF I don't understand your deletion issue. If you're calling this code `After Delete` (and using `Trigger.old`), the deleted `OpportunityLineItems` should not be getting summed (because deleted records aren't retrieved in queries without the `ALL ROWS` keyword(s)). Are you sure it's not just an issue of you not refreshing the `Opportunity` detail page after deleting an `OpportunityLineItem`?

Comment: @JMDF as for the discount formula, it needs to be done in Apex (can't be done with SOQL aggregate functions). I think this is something you should try to figure out on your own. I think I put plenty of comments in my code, and you have the formula that you want to use. You have all the information you need; you just need to put it all together. I'll give one hint and say that it'll probably be easier if you have a variable outside of `oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(...));`

Comment: Hi derek I actually found a solution already for the Formulas, I am now just working on the Opportunity fields not turning to 0 if there is no product. Thanks for your code man. It really helped a lot.

Comment: Ah, if there aren't any `OpportunityLineItems` on an `Opportunity`, this code won't work. I'll edit my answer to include this situation.

Comment: Hey it's actually working, It's just I'll create another for loop where in if OpportunityLineItem has no value the fields in Opportunity will become 0.

Comment: It's just that it's not auto rendering the page when I delete all of the OpportunityLineItem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47326/discussion-between-jmdf-and-derek-f).

Comment: Hi @DerekF I acutally tried using your code but it throws an error which is  Loop must iterate over a collection type: Boolean in the for loop of the summedOppIds. Thank for the reply man.

Comment: Forgot that `removeAll()` returns a boolean. Updated my final example code, though honestly, this is something you should have been able to do yourself.

Comment: Hi Derek. Thanks, It's working perfectly fine now. I would like to apologize because actually this is my first time using AggregateResult and I guess there is not enough instructions on how to use it, but thanks to you. My understanding with AggregateResult is now enriched. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad that it's working. I only meant that you should have been able to figure out what was going on with the error about looping over a boolean instead of a collection type. Basic google searching and using the Apex documentation that Salesforce provides is one path to becoming a more independent and knowledgeable developer.

Answer (score 1):

This is after trigger, so it means it will be triggered after the change has been stored in the database. So if you change the data in opporList, it won't change them in your database. What you need to do here is do the DML explicitly.

Below is the code:

```
public void TotalField(List<OpportunityLineItem> o){
    List<Opportunity> opporList = [select id, Total_List_Price__c, Total_End_User_Price__c,
                                Total_End_User_Price_Discount__c, Total_Standard_Price__c,
                                Total_Standard_Price_Discount__c, Total_SPR_Price__c, Total_SPR_Price_Discount__c,
                                Total_Price__c, Total_Price_Discount__c, Total_SPR_Margin__c from Opportunity];

    for(Opportunity oppor : opporList){
        for(OpportunityLineItem oL : o){

          oppor.Total_List_Price__c =+ oppor.ListPrice; //+= field for summation
          //insert calculation
          //another for loop for the value
        }
    }
    update opporList; //Add this
}
```

Comment: Well basically the Opportunity.Total_List_Price__c value should come from it's child object's OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice.

Comment: @LanchiShi Thanks for the reply. Badly needed this one.